# Theories of truth

Tags: lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy

Not knowing much about logic, I thought that in mathematics saying that a (closed) sentence $\varphi$ in a (formal) theory $T$ is "true" amounted to one of the following notions:

1. Syntactic truth: $\;\quad\qquad\quad\qquad T\vdash \varphi\;\qquad$"$\varphi$ is provable from $T$"
2. Semantic truth or necessity: $\quad T\models \varphi\qquad$ "$\varphi$ is true in every model of $T$"
3. Truth in a standard model: $\quad\;\,M_0\models \varphi \;\;\quad$ "$\varphi$ is true in the standard model $M_0$".

Notice that (the symbolic strings in) 1. 2. and 3. are (or rather stand for) sentences of a suitable metatheory $T^*$, such as a set theory, that describes syntax, semantics, and model theory of $T$.
By the completeness theorem for first order theories, 1. turns out to be equivalent to 2.

(Many in case 3. would call $\varphi$  "just true" or "actually true" or "true in the real world". But for me, not being a Platonist, "the real world" in mathematics is not an expression endowed with any meaning, unless you fix a set-theoretic metatheory in which you encode syntax, semantics, models, etc *and* you choose a specified model)

For example, if $T$ is $PA$, $M_0$ would be the usual structure $\mathbb N$ on the set $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ of finite von Neumann ordinals as constructed (in the sense of defined) in $ZFC$. If $T$ is $ZFC$, then $M_0$ would be... I don't know, the "cumulative hierarchy" (but this of course is without meaning, unless you specify a metatheory that is able to talk about classes, or assume inaccessibles).

I thought 1. 2. 3. was all there was to say until, to my surprise, I found out that handreds-of-pages long [books](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/philosophy/logic/epistemic-lightness-truth-deflationism-and-its-logic?format=HB#xI6q71iFHZ1U3ZRQ.97), along with technical articles, can be written about the very concept of truth, filled not only with more or less compelling philosophical arguments but also with nontrivial theorems. So apparently there are such things as *theories of truth* in mathematical logic. Also, which due to my ignorance I didn't know, they are a somewhat classical subject explored, among others, by Tarski and Kripke.

The objective of a theory of truth is roughly to define a *truth predicate* $\mathrm{True}(.)$, specify suitable axioms for it, and draw the consequences. This is usually done in a theory that can interpret its own syntax, for example $PA$. Let's call $\langle\varphi\rangle$ the Goedel number of $\varphi$.

Oftentimes a theory of truth is motivated by a specific philosophical view. One possible view on truth (shared by the author of the book linked above) is called deflationism:

$$\textrm{"Snow is white" is true iff snow is white.}$$

Accordingly, the truth predicate is formally introduced by means of certain "Tarski biconditionals"

$$\mathrm{True}(\langle\varphi\rangle)\leftrightarrow\varphi$$

as axioms for sentences $\varphi$ of $PA$, along with suitable other axioms governing it such as maybe $\mathrm{True}(\langle\varphi\rangle\wedge\langle\psi\rangle)\leftrightarrow\mathrm{True}(\langle\varphi\rangle)\wedge\mathrm{True}(\langle\psi\rangle)$.

What is perhaps surprising is that the resulting theory (which expands the language of $PA$ and adds new axioms) is not always syntactically and/or semantically conservative over $PA$.

> **Q.** Do theories of truth have any applications in mathematics or logic (that is, outside of the part of mathematical logic specifically tailored to examine philosophical assumptions about truth)?

> **Q.** Why the insistence in using the same theory (such as $PA$) both as object theory and metatheory to be expanded with the truth predicate? (Is this to mimick natural languages?)

> **Q.** What if one wanted to define a (family of) truth
> predicate(s) in the language of $T^*$ by
> $\mathrm{True}_T(\langle\varphi\rangle):=(T\vdash\varphi)$? [More pedantically, it should be something like $\mathrm{True}_T(x):=(\exists\varphi\in\mathrm{Sent}(T):x=\langle\varphi\rangle\wedge(T\vdash\varphi)$) ]. Given $T$, am I correct this would be a well defined predicate of $T^*$? I realize this is not mathematically interesting in the sense that all it does is spelling out tautologically the notion of provability. But does it correspond to some philosophical view (such as, idk, some sort of Carnap-style pluralism?)?

> **Q.** With the choice $\mathrm{True}_T(\langle\varphi\rangle):=(T\vdash\varphi)$ the sentence $\neg\mathrm{True}_T(\langle\varphi\rangle)\rightarrow\mathrm{True}_T(\langle\neg\varphi\rangle)$ is *not* a theorem of $T^*$ (because of Goedel's first incompleteness theorem). Are there interesting theories of truth that have this property?

Comment: "What is perhaps surprising is that the resulting theory (which expands the language of $\mathsf{PA}$ and adds new axioms) is not always syntactically and/or semantically conservative over $\mathsf{PA}$." By the completeness theorem, syntactic and semantic entailment over a theory coincide so there's no need to distinguish between types of conservativity here. (That said, there **is** a strengthening of conservativity which only makes sense semantically, namely "Every model of the original theory can be expanded to a model of the new theory," but that's much stronger than mere conservativity.)

Comment: "Why the insistence in using the same theory (such as ) both as object theory and metatheory to be expanded with the truth predicate?" I don't understand what this is asking. It seems to me that $\mathsf{PA}$ is only required to play one role here (although we may also want to adopt it as the metatheory): namely, as the theory whose comparison with its "truth expansion" we're studying. "How does PA compare with truth-PA" is a (type of) question which can be asked in any metatheory. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Re: your third and fourth questions, this really comes down to how we interpret the term "truth" and distinguish "theory of truth" from "theory of provability (or similar)." I would consider commutation with negation to be a core feature of truth, and so notationally would never use "$True_T$." Others may disagree with me on that point. But I think that aspect may be better suited for philosophy.stackexchange.

Comment: Re: the first question, I don't know what you consider an application exactly, but one relevant term is "satisfaction class" in the context of arithmetics or set theories; see [here](https://www.winterschool.eu/files/1090-Truth_theories_and_satisfaction_classes_over_models_of_set_theory.pdf) for some interactions between satisfaction classes and saturation principles.

Comment: @Noah Schweber: thank you for the comments. Re PA as a metatheory: now that you make me notice this, probably I was just confusing "theory" with "language": indeed for the sentence $True(\langle\varphi\rangle)\leftrightarrow\varphi$ to even be stated the language of the truth theory must be that of the object theory (plus the new truth predicate symbol). But if the setting is completely general, we only need the $\langle.\rangle$ to make a sentence of $T$ into a term of $T^*$ and apply $True(.)$ - the languages of T and T* may be completely arbitrary.

Comment: Yes, that's right, and for example (being a bit vague here) set theory has no problem adding a truth predicate for arithmetic since in set theory we can define the standard model of arithmetic and its theory.

Comment: "Theories of truth" seems like a topic in philosophy rather than math.  I'm used to "true" being in reference to some particular model M.  I.e. "$M\models\phi$" means $\phi$ is true in M.  If M is the standard model we'd just say $\phi$ is true.  The metatheory and object theory don't have to be the same and usually the metatheory will be set theory if it is supposed to discuss models.  The key idea is that the statement about truth is made in the metatheory rather than the object theory.  Indeed, Gödel's big insight was an object theory like PA can express provability, though not truth.